# Can a symmetry of a Lagrangian be of order higher than the order of the Lagrangian itself?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, gauge-theory

[image]

In book "Quantization of gauge systems" by Henneaux and Teitelboim, one of the exercises (see picture) was to show that any symmetry of Lagrangian $L$, if $L$ depends only on the generalized coordinates and its first derivative, involving higher order time derivatives of generalized coordinates can be decomposed as sum of two parts: first part depends only on coordinates and first derivative while the second part must vanish on shell.

I am having trouble beginning to prove that, so if someone can give me a hint, I would be very grateful.

Comment: it doesn't seem all that deep, on shell we can always express $\ddot q$ as some function of $\dot q,q$ (by the EOM), say $\ddot q=k(\dot q,q)$. So $f(\ddot q,\dot q,q)$ can be written as $f=f(k,\dot q,q)-(f(k,\dot q,q)-f(\ddot q,\dot q,q))$, which is a function of $\dot q,q$ only, plus something that vanishes on-shell. Higher order derivatives are the same, the EOM allow you to write any $q^{(n)}$ as some function of $\dot q,q$.

Comment: If Lagrangian is singular (i.e. matrix of second derivatives of L with respect to velocities cannot be inverted) we cannot solve for accelerations in terms of q and dq/dt. That is the whole point.

Comment: H&T explicitly state that the Lagrangian is assumed regular -- which usually means $\ddot q$ is solvable in terms of $q,\dot q$. Is the book using a different definition for *regular*? It might be useful to make the post self-contained, write the precise, relevant definitions and remove everything else (so in particular no screenshots). Thanks.

Comment: No, you are absolutely correct! They said regular and I somehow missed that information when I was trying to solve exercise. I spent hours and hours trying all sorts of things. Thank you very much! 